# convert python dictionary key string to key date

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

Say you have a dictionary:

```
a={'20101216':5,'20100216':1,'20111226':2,'20131216':5}
```

Two keys have the same value. How would I go about printing the the maximum key date (which is a string) and value? Like:

```
5 at 12/16/2013
```

I tried to `for` loop the key and the values and print the max key and max value, but it's not working out.

edit: I originally started out trying to convert an array of string dates to date objects. But it fails [b]

```
b=['20101216','20100216','20111226','20131216']
c=[5,1,2,5]  

z=[]
        for strDate in b:
            g=[datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y%m%d')]
            if g not in z:
                z.append(g)
```

Then from there if it worked I have would of done another for loop on my new array [z] to format each date element properly (m/d/y). Following that I would have zipped both arrays into a dictionary.

Like:

```
d = dict(zip(z,c))
```

Which would have resulted in

```
d={12/16/2010:5,02/16/2010:1,12/26/2011:2,12/16/2013:5}
```

Finally I would have attempted to find max date key and max value. And printed it like so:

```
5 at 12/16/2013
```

But because of the failure converting array b, I was thinking maybe working with a dictionary from the start might yield better results.

Comment: *You tried* Awsom, post what you tried ...

Comment: What is it you're failing to do? Finding which two keys have the same value? Finding the maximum key? Converting a string to a date? You mention all these things in your question and it isn't clear which you're asking about.

Comment: You may use `max(a.values())` to get maximum possible value across dict and then use list comprehension (or `for` loop) over `a.items()` to pick keys that have that value.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

```
max(a.items(), key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

Basically, the problem is that you cant access `dict`'s values directly and you still need to sort your data counting it. So, `dict.items()` gives you a list of tuples, i.e.

```
a.items()
[('20101216', 5), ('20131216', 5), ('20111226', 2), ('20100216', 1)]
```

Then all you need is to get maximum value of this list. The simple solution for getting maximum value is **max** func. As your problem is slightly complicated, you should leverage `max` *key* argument (take a look at [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)) and use "compound" sorting key. In such situation the lambda function is a solution. You can express pretty any thing that you need to sort. So, sorting by 2 values inside tuple with corresponding priority should be

```
max(l, key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0])) # where l is iterable with tuples
```